# Combining two rowsets in ADLA without join on clause

Tags: azure-data-lake

I've got two types of input files I'm loading into an ADLA job. In one, I've got a bunch of data (left) and in another, I've got a list of values that are important to me (right).

As an example here, let's say I'm using the following in my "left" rowset:

```
| ID | URL                     | 
|----|-------------------------|
| 1  | https://www.google.com/ |
| 2  | https://www.yahoo.com/  |
| 3  | https://www.hotmail.com/|
```

I'll have something like the following in my right rowset:

```
| ID | Name  | Regex       | Exceptions | Other Lookup Val |
|----|-------|-------------|------------|------------------|
| 1  | ThisA | /[a-z]{3,}/ | abc        | 091238           |
| 2  | ThatA | /[a-z]{3,}/ | xyz        | lksdf9           |
| 3  | OtherA| /[a-z]{3,}/ | def        | 098143           |
```

As each are loaded via an EXTRACT statement, both are in separate rowsets. Ideally, I'd like to be able to load all the values for both rowsets and loop through the right one to run a series of calculations against the left one to find a match per various business rules. Notably, there's no value to simply join on, nor is it a simple Regex evaluation, but rather something a bit more involved. Thus, the output might just look something like the "left" rowset:

```
| ID | URL                     | 
|----|-------------------------|
| 1  | https://www.google.com/ |
| 3  | https://www.hotmail.com/|
```

Now, a COMBINER is the only UDO I see that accepts two rowsets, but the U-SQL syntax requires that I do some sort of join statement here. There's no common identifier between each of the rowsets though, so there's nothing to join on, which suddenly makes this seem less ideal. Of the attribute options defined at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-programmability-guide#use-user-defined-combiners, I'd like to specify this as a Full because I'd need each of the left values available to evaluate against each of the right ones, but again, no shared identifier to do this on.

I then tried to use a REDUCER that accepted an IRowset in the IReducer constructor as a parameter, then tried to just pass the rowset in from the U-SQL, but it didn't like that syntax.

Is there any way to perform this custom combining in a manner that doesn't require a JOIN ON clause?

Comment: @wBob Added an example, but it doesn't fundamentally change the question. Two rowsets of data with no common identifier. I'm seeking to identify a way to combine them exclusively via business rules in the code-behind rather than via a JOIN on a common value.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be able to use an [IProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-programmability-guide#use-user-defined-processors). This would allow you to analyze each row in the RIGHT set and add a column (with a value based on your business rules) that you can subsequently use to join to the LEFT set.

[Adding a bit more detail]: You could also do this twice, once for the left and once for the right to create an artificial join column, like row_number or some such.

Comment: The goal would be that the right set would come from dynamic data that's periodically refreshed but would follow a consistent format. Thus, I'd need some way to pass in that whole rowset because I'd need to iterate through each to identify a matching set of business rules, then do that comparison. I'd ideally like to avoid just having hard-coded business rules to run against the RIGHT set per your suggestion and would instead prefer to be able to pass in this dynamic data. Thanks for chiming in!